# how can I access to an ID using a method in an object literal?

Tags: javascript, dom, methods, ecmascript-6, object-literal

I am rewriting some code to make it modular but I can't access to the DOM as I did in my spaghetti code.

I tried to add the `getElementById` as propriety (e.g. var `getId = {myid:document.getElementById("myid");}`) and works fine, but when I call it from the method it returns undefined. I think is a problem with the binding but I can't find a solution

`//index.html

//app.js

```
var getId={
cacheDom:function(){
    this.myid = document.getElementById("myid");
}
init: function(){
    conosole.log(this.myid)
}
```

`

it should give: `<div type="button" id="myId">` 
but I get undefinite

Comment: I suspect you are calling cacheDom before the element exists. Make sure your code is after the element in your document. E.G. right before your closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: What's in ```index.html```?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `<body>
        <div type="button" id="myid" >

            </div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>` @Aksen P and @str sorry it didn't attach. @Paulpro the js file should load after the DOM is loaded as you can see from the  example

Comment: Have you called cacheDom anywhere?

Comment: @Paulpro you were right, I called cacheDOM in the init and now works fine. Many Thanks